# Getting nested level radio button value using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have radio buttons defined like this in my JSP:

```
<label>
<form:radiobutton path="userOption"  value=“A”/>
            A
</label>
<label>
<form:radiobutton path="userOption"  value=“B”/>
            B
</label>
<label>
<form:radiobutton path="userOption"  value=“C”/>
            C
</label>


<label>
<form:radiobutton path="userSubOption"  value=“optionOne”/>
            Option 1
</label>
<label>
<form:radiobutton path="userSubOption"  value="optionTwo"/>
            Option 2
</label>
```

And in the controller, I’m getting value depending upon which radio button is selected. For example, if I select A, I'll get `A` in controller. Similarly for  B or C.

However,if I am selecting `C` and then selecting Option 1 or Option 2 radio button, I am not getting its value (`optionOne or optionTwo).

Here's a brief code of my controller:

```
 @Controller         

    @RequestMapping(“/manageLocation")         
    
    public class ManageLocationController {
     
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)         
    public ModelAndView process(ModelAndView mav,@ModelAttribute("ManageLocationForm") ManageLocationForm ManageLocationForm,BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
    
           String userOptions = ManageLocationForm.getUserOption();                
           System.out.println(userOptions);         
           //This code doesn’t work
           String userSubOptions = ManageLocationForm.getUserSubOption();                
           System.out.println(userSubOptions);         
    
    
    }
   }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I will try to in some time. It's just a class with getters and setters defined. So I've a variable `private String userOption` defined and its getter and setter. Similary for `userSubOptions`. One thing I did notice in my UI code is that when I click on Option 1, the radio button C was also selected and the radio button for Option 1 was also selected. I mean if I'm selecting Option 1 or Option 2 radio button, radio button C shouldn't be selected, right?

Comment: you might missing the setter fot the userSubOptions

Comment: I have the setter for userSubOptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try :

```
<span>
    <form:label path = "userOption">userOption</form:label>
    <form:radiobutton path = "userOption" value = "A" label = "A" />
    <form:radiobutton path = "userOption" value = "B" label = "B" />
    <form:radiobutton path = "userOption" value = "C" label = "C" />
</span>
<span>
    <form:label path = "userSubOption">userSubOption</form:label>
    <form:radiobutton path = "userSubOption" value = "optionOne" label = "Option 1" />
    <form:radiobutton path = "userSubOption" value = "optionTwo" label = "Option 2" />
</span>
```

Comment: Ok, I will test it and let you know. Does using a label inside the tag a good practice?

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work. I'm still getting null if I select Option 1 instead of `optionOne`.  I guess I might have to move this nested radio button functionality to a new page so it's no longer nested and behave like two separate radio buttons